# Python newbie: How do I define 'nl' in my program?

Tags: python

New to coding and I'm challenging myself to write a program where the user inputs values into a list and sorts them by another input value. When I run the program, I get a traceback error saying that 'nl' is not defined. I think I may have something out of order or I'm not using something correctly. Some advice would be helpful!

```
def listsort(l1):
  for num in l1:
    n1 = []
    if num <= inp:
      n1.append(num)
      for x in n1:
        print(x, end=' ')

def newlist():
  nl = []
  while True:
    l_inp = input('Add to list: ')
    if l_inp == 'done':
      return nl
    else:
      float(l_inp)
      nl.append(l_inp)
      continue

newlist()
inp = float(input('Enter a number: '))
print('These numbers are less than or equal to', inp)
listsort(nl)
```

Comment: You can't use a variable declared in a function outside that function. Just change `newlist()` to `nl = newlist()`

Comment: You don't save your value from `newlist()`. You need to save it to use it.

Answer (score 0):

`n1` has a function only scope, means can be accessed only inside function.
Declare the variable as `global n1` inside both functions.

Answer (score 0):

nl is declared in newlist and you only have scope to that variable in that function, if you want to access it from outside then you should declare nl outside the function and send it as a parameter to "newlist"

[error in python shell showing scope of nl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXrOk.png)

Comment: Thanks! I declared the variable outside of the function and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are two scopes in Python namely local and global. A local scope variable is declared within a function an that cannot be accessed outside the function in which it is defined. You have defined 'nl' inside the function. So, you can't access that outside that function. Hence, the reason for that error

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question revolves around an idea called *scope*, and understanding scopes will make it much easier to figure out problems like this in the future. Everyone learns differently, so don't feel you *have* to know all this right now, but if you want to know the details, read on!

### Scope

Each variable in your program exists in something called a scope. Here is a diagram of your program. It has three scopes - a *global* scope and a scope for each function, `listsort` and `newlist`. Every function has its own scope, and every Python file has its own global scope.

[image: The program annotated to label three scopes: global, listsort and newlist]

Which scope a variable ends up in depends on where it is introduced. Some ways for variables to be introduced are *assignment* (for example `n1`, `nl`, `l_inp` and `inp` are all assigned with the `=` symbol), as a *for loop variable* (for example `num` and `x` are loop variables) and as a *function parameter* (`l1` is a function parameter). A variable lives in the tightest scope around where it is introduced.

You can see that scopes are *nested*. The function scopes are *inside* the global scope. This is important. You can see that the `inp` variable is in global scope, but it can still be used in the `listsort` scope because the `listsort` scope is *inside* the global scope. Code inside a function scope can "see out" to variables in the global scope. But code in the global scope can't "see in" to variables in function scope.

### Okay, so how do I get the variables out of a function?

The variables in a function's scope go away when the function returns. But you can return the *value* of a variable. Your function `newlist` returns the *value* of `nl`. But where does that value go? Well, nowhere, because your program doesn't assign it to a variable. You can do that by writing:

```
nl = newlist()
```

That will save the value into a new variable called `nl` in the *global* scope. But this is a *different* variable from the `nl` in `newlist`. You can of course use any variable name you like, just because you stored this value in a variable called `nl` inside `newlist` doesn't mean you have to put it in a variable with the same name at the global scope. You could write:

```
gl = newlist()
```

And then later on use:

```
listsort(gl)
```

And that would work just as well.

Comment: This was really helpful information! I love the visuals. I saved the return value as most people here have suggested which got rid of the traceback. The problem is, its not outputting the desired sorted list.

Comment: Yes, you've got a few things there to figure out. Writing your own sorting algorithm is a bit of a challenge! You might want to ask a new question if you can't figure things out on your own. By the way, picking out only the things in a list that have some property is commonly called "filtering", not "sorting". That might help if you're asking another question. Good luck!